# CSS Positioning without using float poperty

Tags: html, css

Can u look this [**link**](http://codepen.io/gslv/pen/VmyEvR?editors=1100)?

Why there **div** are not align each of on side by side? and why there a gap between them? or here is code in body

I know there a lot of another way to solve this but in this case what is the problem going on?

**what is the solution in this prticular case?**

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}

/*main{background:magenta;padding:10px 0px;text-align:center}*/
main{background:magenta;padding:10px 0px;text-align:left}

div{display:inline-block;background:blue;min-height:50px;
width:calc(100% / 3)}


/*issue:- positioning div without using float poperty**

*/
```

```html
<main>

<div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>

  <div class="child"></div>
</main>
```

and in  css

```
<style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}

    main{background:magenta;padding:10px 0px;text-align:left}

    div{display:inline-block;background:blue;min-height:50px;width:calc(100% / 3)}
</style>
```

Comment: @RamanaaGj they don't want to use float (rightfully so)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `display: inline-block` creates whitespace.

To remove that simply add `font-size: 0` to your parent div, in your case `main`

With **Flexbox** you could also do the following:

1. Add `display: flex;` to your parent div, in your case `main`
2. Add `flex: 1;` to your children div and remove the `width`. The children div will automatically take up the available space.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
main {
  background: magenta;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
}
div {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Give a flexbox example too 

Comment: @AndrewBone Made one :)

Answer (score 0):

Because Your Div`s ar bigger then the container, and therefor they wrap to a new line.

Change :

```
div{display:inline-block;background:blue;min-height:50px;width:calc(100% / 3.333)}
```

Or Use [Flex-box](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) instead, its much easier than it looks at first.

Comment: why 3.333 and need more technical detals to understand sir

Answer (score 0):

Add below css.

```
 main{
     display: flex;
     padding-right: 10px;
 }
 div{
    margin-left: 10px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the flexbox solution as suggested by Andrew

**Code:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
main {
  background: magenta;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
div {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</main>
```

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/n26nex4k/1/

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend calculating a third of the width the way you did because if you have more divs inside main, let's say another row of three, they won't go underneath but carry on being side by side.

Anyways, what you can do to fix the alignment is to utilise the flex box.

In your CSS add this to your main:

```
display: flex; 
align-items: center;
```

Comment: flex is nice but limited support

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}

main{background:magenta;padding:10px 0px;text-align:left;display:flex;justify-content:space-between;}

div{display:inline-block;background:blue;margin:1px;min-height:50px;width:calc(100% / 3)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}

/*main{background:magenta;padding:10px 0px;text-align:center}*/
main{background:magenta;padding:10px 0px;text-align:left}

div{display:inline-block;background:blue;min-height:50px;
width:calc(100% / 3)}


/*issue:- positioning div without using float poperty**

hallow can u say that why 
  there div are not align each of on side by side? and why there a gap between them? 
i know there a lot of another way to solve this but in this case what is the problem going on?

**what is the solution in this prticulr case?**
*/
```

```html
<main style="display:flex;">

<div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>

  <div class="child"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Just add style 'display:flex' to your <main> tag. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

**here is another way i try*

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
#new1{background:darksalmon;padding:10px 0px;}

.new1_child{background:green; padding:10px 0px;
width:calc(100% / 4); display:inline-block;text-align:center;color:white}
//without using semantic code write
```

```html
 <section id="new1">
    <aside class="new1_child">lorem3</aside><aside class="new1_child">lorem4</aside><aside class="new1_child">lorem5</aside><aside class="new1_child">lorem6</aside>
    </section>
<!--option 1 align content without flex or float-->
<br><hr>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You can add

   `line-height: 0;
   outline: none;
   vertical-align: top;`

   for your `div` and add `<!--- --->` comment out for the space in between your `div` so that there would be no white space.

```css
    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*main{background:magenta;padding:10px 0px;text-align:center}*/

main {
  background: magenta;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-align: left
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
  background: blue;
  min-height: 50px;
  outline: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

```html
<main>

<div class="child"></div><!---
  ---><div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</main>
```

2. like what they suggest, use `display:flex`
3. Use `margin-right:-4px;` in your div so that it would show like there was no space in the first place. This one is not really a great idea especially for responsive divs but it depends on how good you make your layout.

Comment: Please explain why down vote? When I am giving options?

Comment: @Indranil Yes it isn't but flex is not the only one I answered and yet I get the down vote? It wasn't even my first option.

Comment: i dont do anything for downvote sir and actuly i nvr do this tipe of bad rating to any site as i greatful to all of you to help me to share ur thoughts .